# Given a fixed convex domain $\Omega$ in 3D, for what value $c$ the function $f(c) := \int_{\partial \Omega} |x-c| d \sigma_x$ gets its minimum?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, convex-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded smooth convex domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then consider the following minimization problem:

$$\inf_{c \in \overline{\Omega}} f(c), \quad  f(c) := \int_{\partial \Omega} |x-c| d \sigma_x,$$ where $\sigma$ is the surface measure.

If $\Omega$ is a ball, then it is easy to prove that the infimum is attained only at the center of the ball. I guess for a generic fixed convex domain $\Omega$, the infimum should be attained at the "center" of $\Omega$, but I've no idea how to prove or disprove it, and also I don't know if the "center" is the standard meaning, that is, $c=\frac{\int_{\Omega} x dx}{|\Omega|}  $.

Any comment or hint would be really appreciated.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that it will be in the center. Hint: differentiate and write that all partial derivatives at c are equal to 0.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko, we can always try to find critical point. Here using $\nabla |x-c|=\frac{c-x}{|x-c|}$, I get $\int_{\partial \Omega}\frac{c-x}{|x-c|} d\sigma_x=0$ , but I cannot solve for the $c$. I agree that the critical number may not be at the center, but I believe it should be a point related to the geometry of $\Omega$.  Like when $\Omega$ is a ball, one can really prove $c$ is the center of the ball.

Comment: Of course this is difficult to solve for $c$, but this equation indicates that this is not the center as you conjectured.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko, you are right. Thank you for your comment and time!

Comment: It is not even clear that the critical point (or absolute minimum) is unique, the thing one would like to know before solving for $c$.

Comment: Actually, I think it is clear that the minimum is unique, since $|x-c|$ is a convex function of $c$, and, therefore, so is $f(c)$.